# Реализация конвеера

Tags: python, парсер

Для парсера необходимо реализовать конвеерность:

1. Скачивание;
2. Парсинг.

Процесс скачивания многопоточный. Как реализовать сначала скачивание, а после парсинг? ps Парсер пишеться на python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Действия загрузчика

1. Скачать файл
2. Поместить его в очередь на парсинг

Действия парсера

1. Если очередь на парсинг пустая, то ждать
2. Если не пустая парсить и вернуться к п.1

Разбейте на две программы, чтобы не качать парсером или парсить загрузчиком. Или есть подводные камни?

Comment: Просто не хотелось бы разбивать на два скрипта, ибо этот парсер будет демоном.

Comment: А поподробнее можно? А то "парсер будет демоном" - это значит "скачивание" == "upload" (запрос POST) или что? Или ещё как-то? И в чём всё-таки проблема?

Comment: Решение уже найдено путем создания пула загрузки. Демон это типо всегда работающее приложение которое получает команды извне.